# SendAsync is blocking UI thread

Tags: c#, http, asynchronous, sendasync

Trying to convert part of my program into asynchronous http client call.
Took out part of code (which is below) to test.
Basically an async'ed button with non-blocking (should be to my knowledge) SendAsync(). It should not block UI thread, am I correct? It still blocks it for a reason I cannot currently see.

I've spent last 2 days trying to figure out whats wrong. I implemented non-blocking file write logging and email send features and they work correctly.

Could someone point out what am I doing wrong please?

```
private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    NetworkCredential differentCredToPass = new NetworkCredential("user", "*****", "domain");
    WebProxy wcProxy = new WebProxy("1.1.1.1", 8080);
    wcProxy.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    wcProxy.Credentials = differentCredToPass;
    var httpHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
    httpHandler.UseProxy = true;
    httpHandler.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    httpHandler.Proxy = wcProxy;
    using(HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(httpHandler) )
        {
        try
            {
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://cisco.Com");
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
            textBox1.AppendText(response.StatusCode.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
            }
        catch (Exception ex)
            {
            textBox1.AppendText(ex.Message.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
            throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It appears as though you're running this on the UI thread (`button2_Click`), and since you write something to a UI control (`textBox1`), it has to block until it receives a response. If you want it to not block the UI, use a `BackgroundWorker` or otherwise get a thread from another thread pool, and update the textbox in a callback.

Comment: I moved it to separate function: `public async Task<string> send_Request()` and calling it from button with `string a = await send_Request();`, also removed all referenced to textbox, it still blocks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> non-blocking (should be to my knowledge) SendAsync()

Well, yes and no. Unfortunately, for historical reasons, `SendAsync` is not *purely* asynchronous. Specifically, it does DNS lookup and proxy resolution synchronously. So, to make this fully nonblocking, you would need to wrap that call in a `Task.Run`:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await Task.Run(() => httpClient.SendAsync(request));
```

Comment: I’ll test when i get home. Thanks Stephen! Msdn didn't evn bother to mention it.

Comment: Worth noting that `SocketsHttpHandler` in .NET Core does do async DNS.