# HttpClient SendAsync blocks main thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

I have written a little winforms application that sends http requests to every ip address within my local network to discover a certain device of mine. On my particular subnet mask thats 512 addresses. I have written this using backGroundWorker but I wanted to tryout httpClient and the Async/Await pattern to achieve the same thing. The code below uses a single instance of httpClient and I wait until all the requests have completed. This issue is that the main thread gets blocked. I know this because I have a picturebox + loading gif and its not animating uniformly. I put the GetAsync method in a Task.Run as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56029988/sendasync-is-blocking-ui-thread) but that didn't work either.

```
    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var addresses = networkUtils.generateIPRange..
        await MakeMultipleHttpRequests(addresses);
    }


    public async Task MakeMultipleHttpRequests(IPAddress[] addresses)
    {
        List<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> httpTasks = new List<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>();
        foreach (var address in addresses)
        {
            Task<HttpResponseMessage> response = MakeHttpGetRequest(address.ToString());
            httpTasks.Add(response);
        }
        try
        {
            if (httpTasks.ToArray().Length != 0)
            {
                await Task.WhenAll(httpTasks.ToArray());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\thttp tasks did not complete Exception : {0}", ex.Message);
        }

    }

    private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> MakeHttpGetRequest(string address)
    {
        var url = string.Format("http://{0}/getStatus", address);
        var cts = new System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource();
        cts.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        HttpResponseMessage response = null;
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
        response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request, cts.Token);
        return response;
    }
```

I have read a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55992003/can-httpclient-sendasync-not-block-gui-thread) but my gui thread is not doing much. I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24983635/httpclient-sendasync-using-the-thread-pool-instead-of-async-io) that I maybe running out of threads. Is this the issue, how can I resolve it?
I know its the Send Async because if I replace the code with the simple task below there is no blocking.

```
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
       Thread.Sleep(1000);
    });
```

Comment: I know what's happening. you have 500+ Http requests all throwing timeout exceptions at once.... Watch your "Output" window while it's locked up.

Comment: I think OP means there is some work done on the UI thread, and its interrupting the smooth animation of the gif. Yes just because you are using the async and await it actually doesn't imply threads at all, and continuations will run in the UI context. If you want to be assured everything is completely isolated from the ui, i suggest offloading. Task.Run( everything)

Comment: Yes i do have timeout exceptions, i put a try a catch around the Send Async but shouldn't they be handled safely on their own threads? @JoePhillips blocking meaning , the loading spinner gif gets stuck, also i cannot click any ui buttons.

Comment: What I am saying: It's locking up because you are in Debug mode and the debugger is trying to say "hey, you got an exception" 500 times at once. Run it in Release mode and see if it still locks up. Also, you are doing timeouts wrong.

Comment: @Andy , yes that worked. The gif is not perfectly smooth but it's a lot better, I'm happy to accept this as an answer. Do you mean the setting up of the cancelation token is wrong?

Comment: OK -- added an answer. let me know if you need anything clarified.

Comment: What is your runtime? .NET Framework or .NET Core?

Comment: @PauloMorgado .Net Framework 4.7.2

Comment: `Task.WhenAll` takes an `IEnumerable<Task>` and, internally, creates an array of `Task`s. By invoking `ToArray()` you're forcing the creation of yet another array of `Task`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So one of the issues here is that you are creating 500+ tasks one after another in quick succession with a timeout set outside the task creation.

Just because you ask to run 500+ tasks, doesn't mean 500+ tasks are all going to run at the same time. They get queued up and run when the scheduler deems it's possible.

You set a timeout at the time of creation of 10 seconds. But they could sit in the scheduler for 10 seconds before they even get executed.

You want to have your Http requests to timeout organically, you can do that like this when you create the `HttpClient`:

```
private static readonly HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient
{
    Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
};
```

So, by moving the timeout to the `HttpClient`, your method should now look like this:

```
private static Task<HttpResponseMessage> MakeHttpGetRequest(string address)
{
    return _httpClient.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, new UriBuilder
    {
        Host = address,
        Path = "getStatus"
    }.Uri));
}
```

Try using that method and see if it improves your lock-up issue in Debug mode.

As far as the issue you *were* having: It's locking up because you are in Debug mode and the debugger is trying to say "hey, you got an exception" 500 times all *at the same time* because they were all spawned *at the same time*. Run it in Release mode and see if it still locks up.

What I would consider doing is batching out your operations. Do 20, then wait until those 20 finish, do 20 more, so on and so forth.

If you'd like to see a slick way of batching tasks, let me know and I would be more than happy to show you.

Comment: Using a SemaphoreSlim to throttle the requests would likely be the best way to go about this

Comment: @JoePhillips -- *absolutely*, if he wants to see an example, that's exactly what i would have used. Semaphore with like 20 or so slots.

Comment: Or a TPL ActionBlock.

Comment: @Andy, thanks, yes in release mode , everything works smoothly. I tried setting the httpClient timeout as you suggested but it did not make a difference in debug mode, I guess it's because 99% of the calls will always end with an exception. Please do give an example of doing batch operations, thats very interesting. Marking this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

On .NET Framework, the number of connections to a server is controlled by the [ServicePointManager Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager).

For a client, [the default connection limit](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultpersistentconnectionlimit) is **2** on client processes.

No matter how many HttpClient.SendAsync invocations you do, only 2 will be active at the same time.

But you can [manage the connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/network-programming/managing-connections) yourself.

On .NET Core here isn't the concept of service point manager and the equivalent default limit is int.MaxValue.

Comment: This looks interesting. Do you have more information on when/how this would be useful? Perhaps an example?

Comment: On ASP.NET server applications this number will be higher because it's more likely to be more simultaneous requests to the same host/URL. On client applications it's useful when you need more than 2 connections to the same host/URL. The system is very configurable. Please, look at the docs in the provided links and in the links on those docs.

Comment: Thats very interesting read, thanks. In my case i'm making a single call to multiple hosts so I don't think i am reaching the limit as described. I did try it but it made no difference. However i'll remember to set it to more than 2 when my application does do that.

Comment: Have you verified that the connections are, actually, being made? Either using `netsat` or Fiddler?

Comment: and you see all those 512 connections to the servers at the same time?

Comment: no not the same time and didn't see a difference by increasing defaultconnectionlimit

Comment: milliseconds between each call

Comment: If the invocations are for different hosts, changing that wouldn't make a difference.

Comment: You need to capture a trace of the execution with [PerfView](https://github.com/Microsoft/perfview) to see what's happening.